# Toothbrush joke?

Tags: armed-girls-machiavellism

In episode 6 of Busou Shoujo Machiavellism at about 17:15, there is a scene where Nomura sneaks into a girl's room and finds a toothbrush.

He gets excited and starts brushing his teeth with it. The side character hits him and says "Is now the time for this?"

Is this a common joke or prank as an anime trope? Or was there a more significant plot point that I am missing?

Attached below is a screen shot of the scene for easier reference:

[image]

Comment: Probably the "indirect contact" joke, similar to drinking from same straw, but not sure..

Comment: [machiavellianism] would seem to be the best name for a tag as its the primary part of the name of the series. The "busou shoujo" part is rendered in much smaller letters in the title art. The name "machiavellianism" is what's used in the URL for the show's official site: http://machiavellism-anime.jp/

Comment: [armed-girls-machiavellism] just fits into 25 characters, so that's what we're going with, despite the nonexistence of the word "machiavellism". Synonyms have been added for other variants of the title

Comment: I'm not actually watching this show (I watched episode 1 and dropped it), but I had a look at the scene you're referring to. My animey-sense tells me that @AkiTanaka is correct: this is the tired narrative trope where if your mouth touches a thing that has touched another person's mouth, it's basically the same as ~*~kissing~*~ them.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Probably is a reference to the [monogatari toothbrush scene](https://vimeo.com/45930726).

Comment: I doubt it. The entire joke in the Nisemonogatari scene is that one person is brushing somebody _else's_ teeth. This doesn't happen in the scene OP is asking. Indeed, the only similarity between OP's scene and the one in Nisemonogatari is that a toothbrush is involved. This is a tenuous connection, at best.